# Fortify Scan - Objective-C - exclude pod directory

Tags: objective-c, security, fortify

How to exclude `Pods` folder from Fortify scans in Objective-C?

I tried `exclude` command in `sourceanalyzer`, but no success,

```
sourceanalyzer -b $BUILDID -exclude "/Pods"
```

I also read somewhere that exclude won't work in Objective-C. Not sure how true that is. Any help here folks?